# Pass a list of files to sed to delete a line in them all

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to do a one liner command that would delete the first line from a bunch of files. The list of files will be generated by grep command.

```
grep -l 'hsv,vcv,tro,ztk' ${OUTPUT_DIR}/*.csv | tr -s "\n" " " | xargs /usr/bin/sed -i '1d'
```

The problem is that sed can't see the list of files to act on.I'm not able to work out what is wrong with the command. Please can someone point me to my mistake.

Comment: Have you verified the output of the `tr` step? Have you tried passing one or two filenames to the `xargs` step? Have you tried done both of those things and combined them into a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hello Beta - Yes I have. Doesn't work. The output of grep is a list of files separated by spaces.

Comment: What about the "passing one or two filenames to the `xargs`" step?

Comment: Show some result after `grep` and after `tr`.

Comment: the tr is not necessary, xargs will handle that. Your command looks valid, maybe you have some file names containing spaces - in this case the tr is poisonous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line numbers in `sed` are counted across all input files. So the address `1` only matches once per sed invocation.

In your example, only the first file in the list will get edited.

You can complete your task with loop such as this:

```
grep -l 'hsv,vcv,tro,ztk' "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"*.csv |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    sed -i '1d' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and grep):

```
grep -l 'hsv,vcv,tro,ztk' ${OUTPUT_DIR}/*.csv  | xargs sed -i '1d'
```

The `-l` ouputs the file names which are received as arguments for xargs.

The `-i` edits in place the file and removes the first line of each file.

N.B. The `-i` option in sed works at a per file level, to use line numbers for each file within a stream use the `-s` option.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is this  apart from the one posted by Dan above -

```
for k in $(grep -l 'hsv,vcv,tro,ztk' ${OUTPUT_DIR}/*.csv | tr -s "\n" " ")
do
    /usr/bin/sed -i '1d' "${k}"
done
```